# Docker Image Entry Point Script Not Found

Tags: docker

I have a `Dockerfile` like:

```
FROM frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8:slim
ADD build/libs/zuul*.jar /app.jar
ADD src/main/script/startup.sh /startup.sh
EXPOSE 8080 8999
ENTRYPOINT ["/startup.sh"]
```

`startup.sh` looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "Environment value required"
    exit 1
fi

java -jar -Xms400m -Xmx400m -Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j2-qa2.xml -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8999 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=8999 app.jar
```

But when I run it with `docker run`, I got `docker: Error response from daemon: Container command '/startup.sh' not found or does not exist..`. The shell script has execute permission.

I used the same way to run my other apps and they're all working fine. I wrote the files in Mac and tried to run the container in a Linux machine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out to be the `^M` DOS-style line ending character that caused the issue. But since I'm editing in Mac and I checked several times with vim, I'm pretty sure the starting script in my local machine doesn't have that char. But when opened with vim inside the container, I can see `^M` everywhere. So somehow that char gets added to `startup.sh` when copied into the image, which is weird. That prevents the script from being invoked.

The solution is to add `dos2unix filename` before the ENTRYPOINT in Dockerfile. But make sure that your base image has that utility.

Comment: Hah nice, thanks for telling the community about your findings. Definitely worth taking a note here about this weirdness. Anyway. Good to know you have resolved your issue.+1

Comment: Lost more than an hour because of DOS-style CRLF line endings. For those of you using git client for Windows, be aware when cloning a repo and editing an existing Dockerfile. Remember to convert all the CRLF to LF. Thanks J Freebird!

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem which led me to this thread, however my issue was not quite the exact same as yours. For me the problem was that I was using an alpine base image and my script was referencing `#!/bin/bash`, I just had to update mine to `#!/bin/sh` at the top of my script instead.

Answer (score 1):

> The shell script has execute permission.

Are you sure though? (I mean *within* the container, onced ADDed)
To be sure, I would use the Dockerfile:

```
EXPOSE 8080 8999
COPY src/main/script/startup.sh /startup.sh
RUN chmod 755 /startup.sh
WORKDIR /
ENTRYPOINT ["/startup.sh"]
```

Comment: I got `/bin/sh: CHMOD: not found
 The command '/bin/sh -c CHMOD 755 /startup.sh' returned a non-zero code: 127`

Comment: It's actually lower case `chmod`.  But I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

A container exits when its main process exits. So check that `/startup.sh` is not ending.

Particularly check that this java

```
java -jar -Xms400m -Xmx400m -Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j2-qa2.xml \
  -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom \
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8999 \
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false \
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=8999 \
  app.jar
```

Comment: What do you mean? You mean the `/startup.sh` is not written correctly?

Comment: It seems to be the line ending issue.  I see `^M` at the end of each line when I was inside the container. I opened it with `vim` inside the container. I deleted those characters and I'm able to run it. But outside the container I cannot see those chars with `vim`.  I was doing editing and all the stuff in Mac, I shouldn't get those chars. Any idea?

Comment: I see. I was thinking of this issue, but I didn't see the `^M` chars when I opened it locally with vim, I'm pretty sure it doesn't exist since I'm editing in Mac. When copied over into the container, however, `^M` is everywhere. I have no idea where it came from. Just added `dos2unix` in Dockerfile to clean it. After that, everything goes well.

Answer (score 0):

I think the trouble here is when you specify path like `/app.jar`, it is really difficult to make out where the `current working directory` actually is.

It can be any where and I suspect Docker must have accidentally copy your `start.sh` to a place whatever at that point `./` is.

You might want to ssh into the container and do a `find` to search and see where `startup.sh` is sitting.

1. `docker ps -a` - Find docker container ID
2. `docker -i -t [CONTAINER_ID] /bin/bash` - SSH inside
3. `find . -name "startup.sh"` - Look for file.

If you intend to copy the files through using `./` (current working directory), I think it would be better to specify where `current` is. And you can do this using the `WORKDIR` keyword.

Example:
`WORKDIR /path/to/workdir`

> The **WORKDIR** instruction sets the working directory for any **RUN**, **CMD**,
>   **ENTRYPOINT**, **COPY** and **ADD** instructions that follow it in the
>   Dockerfile. If the WORKDIR doesn’t exist, it will be created even if
>   it’s not used in any subsequent Dockerfile instruction.

That way docker will not get confused.

See: 
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/workdir

Comment: It seems that I cannot ssh into a stopped container. And because it cannot find the `startup.sh`, the container cannot be started.

Comment: Does setting the WORKDIR help it locate the `startup.sh`? Also, worth trying @VonC 's solution too

Comment: I tried both.  I set `WORKDIR /` at the very beginning, but it still doesn't work.