# Check the File in Exited Container

Tags: docker

I have an [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38494794/docker-image-entry-point-script-not-found) invoking the script to start the container. I think I'd better first find a way to tell if the script is actually located in the right place. But neither `docker exec` nor `docker attach` seems to allow me to get into an exited container.

I also tried `docker run -it --volumes-from [exited_container_id] ubuntu`. I thought I might be able to see the file system in ubuntu but I cannot find the mounting point. Is there any way for me to login to an exited container and see the files that I `ADD`ed?

Comment: Maybe try to ADD your file without already executing it so that the container will run. Than you're able to exec and check the location.

Comment: Can you start it as interactive container `docker run -it <container> /bin/bash` and see if the file is there or not?

Comment: @ganesshkumar It still tries to start the container first. So I'll encounter the not found error before anything else.

Comment: @JFreebird, Can you remove the ENTRYPOINT from your Dockerfile and try it in interactive mode? It is the easiest way to check what is there inside the running container before running any command

Comment: @ganesshkumar you mean remove it and `docker run -it <container> /bin/bash` ?

Comment: Remove it, build an image from the Dockerfile and then run it using the command you mentioned above?

Comment: @ganesshkumar That worked for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the script is located in the right place adding a `RUN ls -l /` line in your Dockerfile and building the image

```
FROM frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8:slim
ADD build/libs/zuul*.jar /app.jar
ADD src/main/script/startup.sh /startup.sh

RUN ls -lah /

EXPOSE 8080 8999
ENTRYPOINT ["/startup.sh"]
```

Then just build the Dockerfile

```
docker build -t myapp .
```

You should see the result of that `ls` in the output of the build

Comment: I see it in the root directory with permissions `-rwxr-xr-x`.  So I suppose this is what I expected. As to why I cannot invoke it, I need to figure out some other way to investigate. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: I cannot see the `ls` outputs when I tried to build it again. After the command is run, it just goes to the next build step, without the outputs.

Comment: try with `--no-cache` and after all don't forget remove that line from Dockerfile